# Cisco 881w AP factory reset

Tags: cisco, ios, reset, access-point

If I want to return to the factory IOS and configurations of the AP only, I must issue this command:

```
service-module wlan-ap0 reset default-config
```

right?

But which IOS is going to replace the current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will only reset your configuration so the IOS should be the same as the one running on the device when you issue the command.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/860-880-890/software/configuration/guide/admin_ap_ps9572_TSD_Products_Configuration_Guide_Chapter.html#wp1057756 seems to confirm this.

Comment: But if I have a corrupted IOS, how do I reset it do the factory default also?

Comment: The "hard" bit is getting the IOS image file.                      Put the new IOS in the TFTP server's directory, then run this from the AP's command line (not in configure terminal mode):
archive download-sw /overwrite /reload tftp://10.20.30.xx/name-of-image-you-downloaded
Let it run the update, it will reboot itself.

Comment: Jontas, I cannot run any of these command ("archive" command) from the AP module, it is corrupted.

Comment: This is a bit from what I actually knows then ... I think this post might help you though http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/network-technologies/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-ios-in-cisco-1250-access-point-series-2/

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me out. Creating a bridge from the Host Router to the Integrated AP allowed me to copy files from the host routers flash via TFTP.
http://rickysnetworkblog.blogspot.com.au/2016/03/ios-recovery-on-embedded-ap-in-cisco.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but the salient information from the link should be included in the post. 
In general it’s best for answers to be as self-contained as possible.
Always quote the most relevant part of the external resource as its URL may change or go permanently offline.